# Generated unique value to set the key and then pass the same value into the onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-handling, dom-events

I am working on a React project. I am having a div in my component. I give a key to this div using `uuid.v4()` function (generates random number). Now when I click this div, I want to send this key as a parameter to click event. I am not able to solve how to sent the key to the click event when they are of same component. I am trying to do it like this

```
<div className="img-scroll">
                        {this.state.imageSearchResults.items.map((item, ind) => {
                            return <div className="person-image"
                                        key={uuid.v4()}
                                        onClick={()=>{this.onGoogleImageSelect()}}
                                        style={{backgroundImage:`url(${item.link})`}}>
                            </div>
                        })}
                    </div>
```

click event function:

```
onGoogleImageSelect(e){
        console.log(e.target.key)
    }
```

This gives me error:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
> ```

How can I send that key to the click event?

Comment: because you are not passing the event object, use this: `onClick={(e) => {this.onGoogleImageSelect(e)}}`.

Comment: Printing "undefined" in console now onClick

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, you need to pass the argument to onGoogleImageSelect,

```
<div className="img-scroll">
                        {this.state.imageSearchResults.items.map((item, ind) => {
                            return <div className="person-image"
                                        key={uuid.v4()}
                                        onClick={(e)=>{this.onGoogleImageSelect(e)}}
                                        style={{backgroundImage:`url(${item.link})`}}>
                            </div>
                        })}
                    </div>
```

Comment: Printing "undefined" in console now onClick

Comment: console log "e" and check if your properties are there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value into the function call in the onClick handler

```
<div className="person-image"
     key={uuid.v4()}
     onClick={()=> this.onGoogleImageSelect(uuid.v4())}
     style={{backgroundImage:`url(${item.link})`}}>
</div>
```

and then accept that parameter in your function.

```
onGoogleImageSelect(uid){
   console.log(uid)
 }
```

Official docs reference https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers

Comment: Printing "undefined" in console now onClick

Comment: I don't think e.target.key is a thing, change it to e.target.value `onGoogleImageSelect(e){
        console.log(e.target.value)
    }`

Comment: How will I get key then ?

Comment: uuid.v4() generates a random number everytime it  is used. So In your answer the key and the passed value will be different.

Comment: But that is not your question. That is a seperate issue. This is how you pass a value into an event handler.

Comment: I want to pass the key into event handler or get the key of div in the event handler. That is my question. My question is not to just pass anything inside event handler.

Comment: Can you explain why the key and the uid need to be the same. You could just use the `ind`  index parameter for the key if you want the value to be the same. The index will increment with each instance and therefore will always be unique. Does this work for your use case?

Comment: I suggested an edit to your question since what you were asking was not clear.

Comment: "Now when I click this div, I want to send this key as a parameter to click event." This part of my question was clearly stating the point.

Comment: Also I want to identify which div was clicked. That is the reason I want the key parameter to be captured onClick.

Comment: Which parameter you are talking about is unclear. More importantly, your question title says something completely different. I've rewritten it for you, you just have to accept the edit.

Comment: The index value doesn't help you identify which div was clicked? This how this is how I usually do this kind of reference. I don't know how to use uuid the way you want but if you can elaborate why you need to do then it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164806/discussion-between-apurvg-and-josh-pittman).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a dynamically generated uuid you can just use the `ind` index in your map function.

```
{this.state.imageSearchResults.items.map(
   (item, ind) => <div className="person-image"
                       key={ind}
                       onClick={()=>this.onGoogleImageSelect(ind)}
                       style={{backgroundImage:`url(${item.link})`}}>
                  </div>
   )
 }
```

You then accept this value in your function

```
onGoogleImageSelect(value){
     console.log(value)
}
```

The `ind` value will increment with each item and will therefore be unique every time.

It might be better to set an id attribute for future reference rather than using the key attribute.

```
{this.state.imageSearchResults.items.map(
       (item, ind) => <div className="person-image"
                           key={ind}
                           id={ind}
                           onClick={()=>this.onGoogleImageSelect(ind)}
                           style={{backgroundImage:`url(${item.link})`}}>
                      </div>
       )
     }
```